# How to specify path to groovy script file

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-groovy, extended-choice-parameter

I currently have my groovy script in workspace under sdkTools/tools/at-jenkins/helloWorld.groovy

I dont know in what form this file path needs to be
[image]

I have tried:

$WORKSPACE/sdkTools/tools.....

sdkTools/tools...

/sdkTools/tools...

../helloWorld.groovy

None worked. Script contains simple return of HelloWorld text. I tried putting same script into "Groovy Script" option and it worked.

```
return "hello world"
```

[image]

As you can see nothing shows on Dialog_test parameter if groovy file is selected.. But if I hardcore script I get hello world there.

Any help is much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a full path. It won't work for the first time because the script needs to be approved first. However, I recommend using [Scriptler plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/scriptler/), so the scripts are approved straight away. Scriptler creates scripts in `/var/lib/jenkins/scriptler/scripts`, so if you e.g. create `test` script, you need to use its absolute path with extension in your Extended Choice Parameter configuration - `/var/lib/jenkins/scriptler/scripts/tets.groovy`, so it looks like e.g.:
[image]